# What would be the best statistical analysis test to find statistical significance between two data sets that do not generally have a mean?

Tags: statistical-significance

For example, if you were looking at Gender and then the frequency/presence of a disease, which test would be best to determine if there was statistical difference between the two diseases?

The sample sizes might also be different for each disease though, like the below.

| Gender | Diabetes | High Blood Pressure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Male | 6000 | 11000 |
| Female | 5000 | 6000 |

Comment: 1. Look up analysis of categorical data, as that is what you have (presence or absense of disease).

Comment: 2. Note that people can have both diabetes and hypertension.

Comment: 3. You haven't given the overall sample size. How many people don't have either condition?

Comment: There are several possibilities, but without the missing information as above, any answer might be misleading.